# KendoUI Numeric Textbox Up/ Down Buttons Broken in IE 11

Tags: kendo-ui

The title just about says it all. I'm using KendoUI, I believe the version is something like 2013.2.716. Anyway I have a Numeric Textbox and the Up and Down arrows work fine in Chrome and Mozilla but are broken in IE 11. Pretty sure they worked fine in IE 10. Interested in hearing a fix or workaround, including removing the up/ down arrows entirely.

Thanks,
Bryce

Comment: They work correctly in IE11 for me if I view the numeric text box demo: http://demos.kendoui.com/web/numerictextbox/index.html maybe you aren't using the latest version of Kendo (that demo page uses version 2013.2.918), or have some CSS of your own that is messing with it?

Comment: As a side-note, in the newer versions of Kendo UI you can get the version by opening dev tools and checking the value of `kendo.version`

Comment: Yeah I noticed if I view the demo itself in IE11 it works fine. Going to investigate with the rest of my team. No CSS btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For hiding the arrows or spinners you can do this

HTML

```
<input id="initial" />
```

Javascript

```
//hide spinners;
var numeric = $("#initial").kendoNumericTextBox({
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    step:1,
    value:25
}).data("kendoNumericTextBox");

numeric.wrapper
       .find(".k-numeric-wrap")
       .addClass("expand-padding")
       .find(".k-select").hide();
```

Comment: So that's what "spinners" meant...

Hides the spinner, still curious if anyone knows how to get it to work with the arrows on IE 11.

Comment: The correct way to hide the spinners is to set `spinners: false` in the configuration. http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/numerictextbox#configuration-spinners

Comment: Yeah that looks better too.

Comment: What do you mean by correct way @CodingWithSpike.. This code also do the job.There are so many ways to found the solution.Dont forget that..

Comment: I'm having the same issue with IE 11 not working with the arrows on Numeric Textboxes. The demo works in IE 11 but I bought into Kendo because it is cross platform now I have to have every user revert back to IE 10 until it is resolved. Not fun Kendo!

Comment: @AlanFisher This is fixed since version 2013.2.918, so all you need to do is upgrade